# A better, efficient way to preload gifs/images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a base gif that swaps to another gif that's chosen randomly from a list of 5 when clicked. Simply using one `<Image />` and changing its source causes it to disappear from the view while loading.

To prevent that, I'm trying to preload all the gifs that I need while setting dimension of the other gifs to 0x0 as shown below.

```
const gifs = [
  { src: require('../../assets/animate1.gif') },
  { src: require('../../assets/animate2.gif') },
  { src: require('../../assets/animate3.gif') },
]
const showIndex = 1

// within the render function
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.changeGif}>
  <View>
    { gifs.map(gif, index) => {
      let style = showIndex === index ? styles.show : styles.hide
      return (
        <Image
          source={gif.src}
          style={style} />
      )
    }
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

This works well if there are only two images. But if I start adding 3 or more the performance drops. Is there a better way to preload images, in my case gifs?

Comment: Isn't the performance directly based on the client-side's ability to download the information? Also, you haven't shown the `changeGif` function.

Comment: If you resize the images to 0x0 aren't you needlessly wasting time doing bicubic scaling of the images?  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: You could keep another element with a spinner gif (which will be the only image you pre-load) behind the "real" element. So you see the spinner as a "transition".

Comment: @Makaze my images are not downloaded and are stored locally within the source code folder. My changeGif function simply changes the state where the Image component's source depends on.

@ Roberto yeah I think so too! But [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2314) is saying that there's no official support for image preloading yet and suggest the said solution.

@ r0hitsharma: I needed a "seamless" transition between the first image and the second so only preloading is the only solution that I can think of.